# In Catan, why do knights allow you to move the robber and steal?

Tags: catan

What do knights have to do with making a robber go where you want and steal from your competition for you? Are they all corrupt knights in league with the same robber?

Comment: One of many reasons why it was a bad idea to change the name of the soldier cards.

Comment: I agree that this question is primarily opinion-based. However, if someone can find a designer comment on this choice and such things are on-topic, I'd feel this should be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thematically, the knight is maintaining order by chasing away the robber from your lands. Mechanically though, if knights could *only* move the robber then developing and activating knights wouldn't be as interesting and worthwhile, so you get to steal too. Which means thematically, the robber... sends you a gift for not jailing him instead?

Comment: The knights demand a shrubbery.

Comment: Thematically, is a good context to analyze this from. And those carefully chosen words still leaves room for the knights to not be totally corrupt, which seems to match the overall spirit of the game.